# BoxCollider2D component attached to the Board object not responding to OnMouseDown method unless I do something weird

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to create a match3 game. Game is simple and consists of 2 scenes, MainScene where you choose the level and LevelScene where you play the level. Everything is fine with the MainScene but LevelScene causes problems. Aside the top stats panel, I have an Image object, named Board, with no image asset in it other than color with half opacity. This Board is responsible for level management. It controls the moves and score counts. It also read a file to generate the tiles out of 4 prefab: crown, book, shield, leaf. These prefabs' Raycast Target property is disabled and named after their location inside the Board object and are put in the right place in the Start() method of the Board object. Next step is to catch mouse input done onto the board and decide which 2 objects are to be switched and the problem starts here.

As I said before, Board object has a collider attched to it and, in Start() method, under some constraints, it resizes itself according to the board size it read from the storage. (e.g. It is drawn as 780x1100 but for the level 1 it converts itself to 770x1076). For now the box collider is not resized and stays in 780x1100 dimension (It perfectly covers the board object).

However, unless I make the collider enormously big compared to the board object, it does not responds to the mouse events. While trying to find how big it should be so that it only covers the board object, I found out that there is a specific size setting where it is still bigger than the board object but only covers the right half of the board. It made me think that the collider is shifted to the right when game is run, however, while game is running, Scene tabs shows collider in the right place. Since it is shifted to the right, I set an offset to it: -780x-1100, having the collider outside the board object but attached to the bottom left side. This way I could achieve a working collider object that has the same size with the board despite getting weird errors in the console. Now problem is, collider now responds even when I click outside the board. Where do I make the mistake?

Here is some pictures representing the structure:

[Level compiled from the BoardManager.cs script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apBdk.png)

[Collider in the original position (Does not work on click to any position)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ78h.png)

[Collider when placed outside in order to preserve the desired dimension (Works but registers outside clicks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42F73.png)

[Expanded collider (Works but registers outside clicks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwEnc.png)

[Scene structure before run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7MPp.png)

[Scene structure after prefabs instantiated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4FN9.png)

Comment: On your camera do you have a `PhysicsRaycaster2D` component? As alternative: Why using colliders at all? Seems to be basically a 2D UI so why not use UI (`Image` / `Button`) components?

Comment: Hey @derHugo , I added a `PhysicsRaycaster2D` component and did not help. The board object is an Image essentially. I can use Input.GetMouseButtonDown()` and it works, but then I also need to calculate if the click is inside the desired are or not which could not manage. After 3-4 days of tutorials this is my second day coding something in Unity. So I am a newbie. Can you expand not using colliders a little bit further?

Comment: don't use colliders then at all, use `UI.Image` components -> The `EventSystem` already handles `IPointerXYListener` calls correctly on those by default that's literally how `Button`, `ScrollView`, `Toggle` etc work ... alternatively checkout [`RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint.html) fr going through the `GetMouseButtonDown`  or alternatively you can use [`MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) which afaik works on UI as well

Comment: Thank you @derHugo, `RectangleContainsScreenPoint` did the trick. If you post it as an answer, I can approve it.